# How to pass data from a layout to a page in Sapper?

Tags: svelte, sapper

In Svelte you can pass [props to the content in a slot](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/slot-props).

```
<Component let:message="Hello!">
    <div>
        {message}
    </div>
</Component>
```

When Sapper uses a layout to render a route, the route contents are rendered in a slot too. The problem is that since Sapper takes control of this process it doesn't seem possible to pass a slot prop to a route.

This doesn't work:

```
// _layout.svelte
<slot message="Hello!"></slot>
```

So what is the appropriate way of passing data from a layout to a rendered route? For example `segment`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass it down through context.

One thing to be aware here is that a _layout component won't be recreated when the route change. And Svelte's context is not reactive. Conclusion: you need to wrap your data in a store.

`_layout.svelte`

```html
<script>
  import { setContext } from 'svelte'
  import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

  export let segment;

  const segment$ = writable(segment)

  // this updates the store's value when `segment` changes
  // syntactic sugar for: segment$.set(segment)
  $: $segment$ = segment

  setContext('segment', segment$)
</script>

<slot />
```

In some child page of this layout:

```html
<script>
  import { getContext } from 'svelte'

  const segment$ = getContext('segment')

  $: segment = $segment$

  $: console.log(segment)
</script>
```